# Dynamic Selection of Fields for WHERE Clause in SOQL Queries

Tags: apex, soql

I need to retrieve certain Custom Metadata records from my Custom Metadata Type `Milestone_Template__mdt`, depending on which of my company's regions I am creating `Projects` & `Milestones` for in my code.

The `Milestone_Template__mdt` records have a tickbox on them, which are named like `EU_Milestone__c`, to identify the region that they belong too. *I've deliberately not used a picklist for reasons that I'd be happy to explain the comments, if anyone's wondering.*

To avoid wasting characters, I'd like to avoid writing a separate query for each of the different regions that I could potentially be creating those records for & deciding which query to execute via if / else statements.

Instead I'm hoping that there's a way to write my query to specify which region's records to select, depending on a region that's stored in a variable `:region`.

I had the not so bright idea of referencing the variable like this

```
projectTemplateWithMilestoneTemplates = [SELECT Project_Name__c,
                                        (SELECT Milestone_Name__c
                                           FROM Milestone_Templates__r
                                          WHERE ((:region = 'EU' AND EU_Milestone__c = TRUE) OR (:region = 'NA' AND NA_Milestone__c = TRUE)) AND Test_Record__c = FALSE)
                                           FROM Project_Template__mdt];
```

the idea being that the criteria would only evaluate to `TRUE` if the region was the one specified & the region's tickbox was ticked but it [looks like](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm) that's not allowed.

Is there another way that I can check whether a certain tickbox is ticked on these records, depending on the value stored in my variable? Or failing that, is there another way to approach this process?

---

The data model looks like:

```
Project_Template__mdt
       |
Milestone_Template__mdt
```

Comment: can you post your mdt structure in the question with data

Comment: There's just a metadata relationship from `Milestone_Templates__r` to `Project_Template__mdt`, if that's what you mean?

Comment: yes, thats what, can you post datamodel picture for better understanding

Comment: @SantanuBoral I've added a diagram now, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: If you had a field on the mdt called "region__c" then it'd be easy - any reason not to do that?

Comment: Datamodel doesn't matter - you are just trying to write a shorthand `SOQL` query with a switch in it, correct?

Comment: @CasparHarmer I've used tickboxes instead because I need to attribute the same record to two different regions, for now but in the future it'll only be attributed to one region & I'd like to avoid adding a picklist value (shouldn't be a text field, in case of typos) for every combination of regions. RE: your 2nd comment, yes that's correct.

Comment: I forget if you can add calcs to custom metadata types... if so, then just calc the value into a comma delimited list.... ok you can't

Comment: @CasparHarmer I'm not 100% sure what you mean there, could you please post an example?

Comment: You could try different relationships per region (still would have to query the lot and select later) or your could define a dynamic query and execute that.

Comment: You can't - I checked

Comment: @CasparHarmer could you please post the dynamic query as an answer? Querying the lot would work but again, it seems like a waste of characters so I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Sure... assuming that it's possible with metadata type queries ... hang on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think your best bet is to use a Dynamic SOQL query (assuming that Salesforce allows Dynamic MDT queries - if not, I'll remove this answer).

Seperate out your region condition and then just fold it into the main query, then execute like this:

```
String regionClause = ( region == 'EU' ? ' EU_Milestone__c = TRUE ' : 
                       (region == 'US' ? ' US_Milestone__c = TRUE ' :
                                         ' ASIA_Milestone__c = TRUE '));

String query =        'SELECT Project_Name__c,            ';
       query +=       '   (SELECT Milestone_Name__c       ';
       query +=       '    FROM Milestone_Templates__r    ';
       query +=       '    WHERE ' + regionClause + '     ';
       query +=       '       AND Test_Record__c = FALSE) ';
       query +=       'FROM Project_Template__mdt         ';

projectTemplateWithMilestoneTemplates = Database.query(query);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Apologise for the extended ternary operator - of course it could be a series of if elses, but I you wanted to save space :)....

Comment: Thanks, I'm running short of time but I'll get back to you about this tomorrow, if not before.

Comment: Two minor details: (a) your ternary operators won't work as you expect/compile right without more parentheses, and (b) you can't have literal newlines in a string. Other than that, I believe it should work.

Comment: Good point, I'll tidy that up. Was in a bit of a rush

Answer (score 2):

I think would create a utility method that just builds a map of Region to `List<Milestone_Template__mdt>` by looping through all the records to create the map. Then the code can just pass in a region as a param and get back all the records as a list...

Comment: Thanks, I'm running short of time but I'll get back to you about this tomorrow, if not before.

Comment: This should work, but might be CPU intensive compared to a query solution.

Comment: I've accepted Caspar's answer now which is working for me. To be clear, I haven't found that yours doesn't work but I'll defer to SFDCFox's expertise that the query solution is the way to go.

Comment: we all defer to sfdcfox :)