# Setting Dynamic Query Criteria Based On a Variable

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

I need to define a clause for my dynamic SOQL query, based on the value in my `userRegion` variable, by adapting the query from [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/188575/10720).

When I try to use

```
String queueOwnerRegionClause = ( userRegion == 'Asia' ? ' Asia__c = TRUE ' :
                                ( userRegion == 'EU' ? ' EU__c = TRUE ' :
                                ( userRegion == 'NA' ? ' NA__c = TRUE ' )));
```

I get these errors

> Incompatible types in ternary operator: Boolean, String

(error location: 2nd line)

> unexpected syntax: 'mismatched input ')' expecting COLON'

(3rd line)

adding a colon at the end of the 3rd line causes this error instead

> unexpected token: ')'

(3rd line)

There's obviously a simple fix for these errors but I've tried searching for examples of other SOQL that create clauses by using this method & can't find any. I'm not sure which other search terms to use.

What's the correct syntax to use to set the criteria for this clause?

Comment: Your last ternary condition only contains a value for the true statement. What do you want as false value? Which is equivalent to: 'What do you want as value when none of this statement is true?'

Comment: @MartinLezer I don't want to execute the query if the condition evaluates to false. Or in other words, I don't mind what the false value is. I'm happy to assume that the false value is the final region in my criteria.

Comment: Add more braces to lock down how the ternary operators associate with their values i.e. always have them surrounding each  `(boolean ? string : string)`. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407273/why-is-the-conditional-operator-right-associative. Though the code would be clearer (and more likely to compile) using series of `if` statements.

Comment: @KeithC thanks. The code from the answer that I linked to in my question was the first time I've come across ternary conditions so I wasn't aware that they effectively work as if statements. That really helps.

Comment: Don't be put off using them for the simple case of e.g. `String s = b ? 'abc' : 'xyz';` where they work really well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your case, I would recommend using a `Map` instead of multiple ternary conditions. Your question is the proof that the code is unreadable.

So first, you could declare a Map like this:

```
Map<String, String> userRegionToField = new Map<String, String>{
    'Asia'=>'Asia__c',
    'EU'=>'EU__c',
    'NA'=>'NA__c'
};
```

Then, you could check if the map contains the current value. If not, you don't want to execute the query:

```
if(userRegionToField.containsKey(userRegion)){
```

Finally, format your query using the value returned by the map. The whole code would be:

```
Map<String, String> userRegionToField = new Map<String, String>{
    'Asia'=>'Asia__c',
    'EU'=>'EU__c',
    'NA'=>'NA__c'
};
if(userRegionToField.containsKey(userRegion)){
    String queueOwnerRegionClause = userRegionToField.get(userRegion) + ' = TRUE';
}
```